# Wrong value from passing data with external

Tags: c, embedded, extern

I have a problem from passing data between two different files.

The problem is that I get the value of an integer from a file (file2.c) to pass it through a variable in another file by using external (file1.c).

The communication between the two files works very well until I pass a lower value (one or more decades less), which has the effect of keeping the decade of the previous value.
I know, it's not very well explained, but here is an example:

```
Value sended from file2.c:          Value received in file1.c: 
100                                 100

Second value sended from file2.c:   Second value received in file1.c: 
10                                  100
```

With an other example:

```
Value sended from file2.c:          Value received in file1.c:
3003                                3003
Seconde value sended from file2.c:  Second value received in file1.c:
50                                  5003
```

For the code (i take off the useless part to keep the lines that interact with the variable, that is led_blinking):

file2.c

```
int led_blinking=0;

static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  //Convert to integer
  led_blinking=atoi(Buf);
  //send the buffer back        
  CDC_Transmit_FS(Buf, *Len);

  return (USBD_OK);
}
```

fil1.c

```
extern int led_blinking;
int main(void)
{
  while (1)
  {
      if(led_blinking==0)
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,LD2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      }
      else
      {
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,LD2_Pin);
          HAL_Delay(led_blinking);               //HERE
      }

  }
}
```

I'm really blocking it. I feel like I'm missing something really simple but don't know what...

Comment: "it's not very well explained". Yes that's true. What is required is actual code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: But even without code I think there's a clue in your examples - it looks like the second write overwrites data at the beginnign of the file, but leaves whatever else was in the file instead of truncating it.

Comment: That is still not an MVE. Where, when, how is `CDC_Receive_FS` called? Values are not "sent" from one file to another. Files don't send anything. We need to see whether there are other threads involved and if not then how the function calls relate to each other.

Comment: I send the value on USB, this value is catch on the uint8_t* Buf from the CDC_Receive_FS first parameter.. 
I then convert this string to an integer using atoi, and i store this value in the led_blinking integer global data.

Then in the main, within the loop, i just get this value back from the extern data.
And that's all.

Comment: Do you use interrupts or multiple processes in this?

Comment: @Lundin 
Yes completly !

The fact is that when i receive some data from USB, there is an interrupt from the Hardware Abstraction Layer, making the data reaching the CDC_Receive_FS from the IT to the Low Layer to the Application-Side with this CDC function..
At the other side, in my file1.c, i've a main function that process a infinite loop with the wile..

Should i also use an interrupt for the variable i want to pass?

Comment: @Alexandredossantos Then this is likely some race condition bug. You need to protect variables shared with the ISR so that they are written to with atomic access or within semaphores.